# convert async.eachLimit to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, promise

I have such aync code

`async.eachLimit(teams, 1000, fetchTeamInfo, exit)`

I need to convert it to Promise (bluebird)

I thought will be good to make something like:

```
Promise.method (teams, 1000, fetchTeamInfo) ->
  async.parallelLimit arr.map((a, i) ->
    ->
      iterator a, i, arr
  ), limit
```

But not sure is it right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see you're using `Promise.method` so I'm assuming bluebird - bluebird comes with `Promise.map` with already supports what you're looking for with the concurrency parameter:

```
const fn = (teams, concurrency) => Promise.map(teams, fetchTeamInfo, {concurrency});
```

As you see, we didn't really do here much - we can just use `Promise.map` directly :)

In CoffeeScript I think it'd look something like:

```
fn = (teams, concurrency) -> Promise.map teams, fetchTeamInfo, concurrency: concurrency
```

But I haven't written CoffeeScript in almost 3 years.