# Delaying and Throttling an array of Promises with Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, axios

I have an array of endpoints I'd like to query like so:
`const apiList = ['/api1', '/callme', '/thisonetoo']`

Using axios, a promise based library, I can dynamically generate a promise by mapping the array ->

```
Promise.all(apiList.map(name => promiseGet(name))).then(res => ...)
```

This works fine... but it calls the server too fast, and some of the apis get denied, which causes the entire program to mess up.

Is there a way to throttle / debounce and wait 500ms before creating or calling the next endpoint?

Limiting the amount of Promises open isn't enough it seems. I have to perform some sort of "sleep" operation and wait a little bit before calling the next api endpoint in the array.

Comment: Have you looked at [similar Promise throttling questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38385419/1426891)? There are [a lot of general Promise throttling requests](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpromise%5D+throttle), which might help narrow the focus of the question if it's not covered in those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throttle amount of promises open at a given time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385419/throttle-amount-of-promises-open-at-a-given-time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 Promise replacement of async.eachLimit / async.mapLimit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892296/es6-promise-replacement-of-async-eachlimit-async-maplimit)

Answer (score -2):

maybe call them serially?

```
const apiList = ['/api1', '/callme', '/thisonetoo'];

function doNext() {
  const uri = apiList.shift();
  axios.get(uri)
    .then(doNext);
}
```

You can add a `setTimeout` within `doNext` if you want additional throttling.

Comment: that seems to make alot of sense, but it doesn't seem like the data resolves at the end to one array?

Comment: It was just an example, no error or additional handling. You will need to expand the `then` handler to collect the responses. Also verify `shift` should only be called on `length > 0`

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend adding a `concurrency` parameter to the call:

`Promise.all(apiList.map(name => promiseGet(name), { concurrency: 10 })).then(res => ...)`.

You can also use `Promise.delay(500)` to have the method calls wait before executing

Comment: thanks. is this avl in the core api or just third party promise libs like Bluebird? and could you show an example of how one could use the delay? appreciate it!