# Fulfilling a Promise.all with some percentage of the promises rejected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I have a `Promise.all(promiseArr).then(()=>foo())` that I want to do `foo()` even if some percentage of the promises in `promiseArr` rejected.

It's a little ugly to do:

```
Promise.all(promiseArr).then(()=>foo())
.catch(()=>{/*check percentage of rejected promises and if it's good call foo()*/});
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Wait until all ES6 promises complete, even rejected promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424561/1048572)?

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43948154/918910) to a question of how to throttle `Promise.all`. It has a counter variable (`limit`) you can use to check against percent completed.