# Wait for async.maplimit using promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I am attempting to use promise to wait for async.mapLimit. I use it to run several shell scripts at the same time and **I want to wait for all of them to finish executing before I continue past the log 'the end'.** But I always get a undefined when using the return value for promise.

```
var myArray = [5,1,2,3,4];

const async = require('async');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function understandPromise() {

    const _waitForMe = async.mapLimit(myArray, 16, doSomeThing, function(err, results){
        console.log(results.length, 'should equal (doSomeThing)', myArray.length);
        console.log('err',err);

    });

    // This also gives undefined
    //const _waitForMe = async.mapLimit(myArray, 16, doSomeThing).then(a,b);
    _waitForMe.then(a,b);

    console.log('the end');

}

function doSomeThing(item, callback){

    let runCmd = './test.sh ' + item;
    console.log('before', runCmd);
    exec(runCmd, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('error', error);
        console.log('stderr', stderr);
        console.log('stdout', stdout);
        console.log('after', runCmd);
        callback(null, item); // or actually do something to item
    });

}

understandPromise();
```

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined* relating to _waitForMe

Why doesn't mapLimit return a promise? I realize I am doing something fundamentally wrong here but i cannot figure out what. Other solutions not involving promise is also something I could consider.

Skipping the callback yields the same problem 'then' of undefined

```
const _waitForMe = async.mapLimit(myArray, 16, doSomeThing);
```

Similar SO questions like this only gives errors [async.mapLimit with Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622495/async-maplimit-with-promise)

**Update 1 after comments**
Commenters have suggested this:

```
async function understandPromise() {
        let results = await async.mapLimit(myArray, 8, doSomeThing);
        console.log('results', results.length);
        console.log('the end');
}
```

But this leads to *(node:567) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.*

I still can't understand why the return of async.mapLimit is undefined when there is no callback involved.

**Update 2**

**I got this to work from the comments but in the end it was that the async module was at an old version 1.5.2 and not at the newer 3.2.0**

Comment: The version you put in comments, works [fine](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/UsingAsyncMapLimit) (of course, none of the shell scripts will succeed in this demo, but that is not relevant). Check version of `async` package is the latest?

Comment: @trincot I tried your code, but it still runs past console.log('the end') before all of the shell script/your sleep has finished. ( async@3.2.0 )

Comment: Of course, you execute that synchronously. If you don't want that, then you must put that in function 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing the callback at the end of the function. The documentation clearly says `it returns a promise, if no callback is passed`. Remove `function(err, results)` and it should start returning a promise.

```
const results = await async.mapLimit(myArray, 16, doSomeThing);
console.log(results.length, 'should equal (doSomeThing)', myArray.length);
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? var _waitForMe = async.mapLimit(myArray, 16, doSomeThing);
    _waitForMe.then(a,b); This also becomes undefined

Comment: @bits sorry what do you mean? I have added the code as well.

Comment: const results = await async.mapLimit(myArray, 16, doSomeThing);                   
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function, so this cannot work

Comment: @bits, Of course you need to put that in an `async` function; that goes without saying. You can execute that async function immediately like an IIFE.

Comment: `async function understandPromise() {`